# interface and abstract class implementation

Tags: java

Just as all subclasses which extend from an abstract class must provide implementation for all abstract methods, do all methods of an interface must do the same for all methods which implement them?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to say that all the *classes* that implement an interface must provide implementation for all its methods. Yes, that's right.

… Unless it's an abstract class implementing the interface, in that case it can leave some of the methods unimplemented (but some concrete class must implement them, eventually). Also, if the interface extends more interfaces, all the methods in those must be implemented, too.

Answer (score 0):

an abstract class leaves the implementation of one or more of it's methods to it's extending classes, it can do the same with the method contracts it inherits through implementing additional interfaces.
 If an abstract class implements an interface, it is not bound to implement any of the the inherited methods. That doesn't mean you can't implement any of them. :D